Firefox, JS, CSS - verticall scroll jumping when element outside of VP changes height
I have a weird issue with Firefox where it scrolls to bottom of the page if content that is outside of viewport changes height. it works without any issues on Chrome. I recorded the issue here https://streamable.com/5zzol4.
There is a code that shuts down (immediately closes) the card when it hides outside the viewport:
function isElementOutsideViewport(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    rect.top >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) ||
    rect.bottom <= 0
  );
}

// Sends state machine event
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (isElementOutsideViewport(recipeCard)) {
    recipeCardStateActor.send({type: 'doShutDown'});
  }
}

// Handles the shutDown event
handleShutDown: () => {
  applyClosedCardStyles();
}

function applyClosedCardStyles() {
  recipeCard.classList.add('cursor-pointer');
  description.classList.add('hide');
  detailButtonWrapper.classList.add('hide');
  cardCloseButton.classList.add('hide');
  image.classList.add('recipe-card-image-height-closed');
  recipeInfoBadges.classList.add('hide');
}

Some of the styles that may be related:
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #FAF3E0;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}

.recipe-card {
    background-color: #fff5EC;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

Markup:
<div class="container">
  <div class="row gap-2 align-items-start">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg order-1" id="js-recipe-list">
      <?php foreach ($data->recipes as $recipe): ?> // rendering recipe cards
        <div class="recipe-card cursor-pointer js-recipe-card">
    ...

Do you guys know any cure for this? Thank you.
I tried to apply several styles that sound "good" on the body, but no luck:
    overflow-anchor: none;
    -ms-scroll-rails: none;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
    scroll-margin: 0;
    scroll-padding: 0;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
    scroll-snap-align: center;

Firefox build: 20240626001103
EDIT:
I also tried following what @Kinan Dira was probably suggesting:


function attachCardCloseListener() {
    const sendCloseEvent = () => recipeCardStateActor.send({type: 'doClose'});
    const sendShutDownEvent = () => {
        if (isElementOutsideViewport(recipeCard)) {
            closeButton.removeEventListener('click', sendCloseEvent);
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', sendShutDownEvent);

            recipeCardStateActor.send({type: 'doShutDown'});

            setTimeout(() => {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: recipeCard.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.scrollY,
                    behavior: 'instant',
                })
            }, 1)
        }
    }

    const closeButton = recipeCard.querySelector('.js-card-close-btn');

    closeButton.addEventListener('click', sendCloseEvent, {once: true});
    document.addEventListener('scroll', sendShutDownEvent)
}




Try to scroll with the mouse wheel instead of the scrollbar (in firefox); does the same thing happen?

@KinanDira That is a bit weird - it does not always happen when scrolling using wheel. I noticed it happens almost always when scrolling slowly, when I scroll faster, it works smoothly. So I tried to unset the scroll event from document after it has been triggered but that did not help. I will record how it behaves with wheel scroll in few hours.

This might not be a scroll-to-bottom issue, but a slight misbehavior happening the moment the document changes height while the user is holding the scrollbar. Because the user holds the scrollbar at a certain point, but what each point on the scrollbar corresponds to changes, this might cause behavior that looks as though the window has scrolled down. I suggest you also try increasing the document height to 9000px  to check whether or not my guess is correct (it seems so given the different behavior for mouse wheel scroll).

@KinanDira I recorded how it behaves when i set html { height: 9000px; } here https://streamable.com/cqgflt. Now the same issue appears in chrome when I increased the height to 9000px.

The behavior I am seeing in this test looks accurate to me: If the open section collapses, it is expected that everything will jump up the height of the collapsed section (the screen top remains the same, but everything on the page moves up a bit). At this point, if you wish to keep the screen focused on the same cards, you would have to move it up manually (check the scrollTo() function). does that make sense?

@KinanDira I tried things like this below but the behaviour is more or less the same and I dont think it is possible to transition without any noticable "jump" of the content.
I tried to get height of the expanded card
const before = recipeCard.getBoundingClientRect().height;
Then send the shut down event
recipeCardStateActor.send({type: 'doShutDown'});
Then get height of collapsed card
const after = recipeCard.getBoundingClientRect().height;
Then scroll by the diff height
window.scrollBy({ top: -before - after, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })

@KinanDira I updated the question with latest attempt.
